# How can I create (in Javascript), a tool to identify the longest repeated pattern in a series of numbers?

Tags: javascript, random, design-patterns, repeat

Alright, long story short, what I overall am attempting to do, is test the level of randomness in a series of multiple thousands of " previously generated seemingly "random" numbers.

I've already written something that will test for the probability of numbers with great success, however, the next step is identifying repeating or recurring patterns.

I'd prefer to get this part done in javascript, so as to avoid having to teach myself another language for the time being.

Now, obviously, I could just use regex and punch in some random sequences myself, but that is not ideal, and would take an infinite amount of time to get the results I'm after.

Comment: You are trying to determine if random numbers are random? Is this even possible?

Comment: Would you consider 1186787119789711879791189798711 to have a repeating 11?  What do you define as a "repeating pattern"?

Comment: Seems like you are asking for an advanced math algorithm you don't have. Not sure this is the place to find it, but good luck.

Comment: I really have no idea where to start on it at the moment. I've thought about stacking loops and functions to keep repeating numbers within the range of the output numbers and reccursively looping back and adding then looking for a match, only to break when it can no longer find matches, but I think I would need some super computers for that to be useful. Also, I expect I would quickly reach the looping limit.

Comment: @JohnKurlak KurlK - yes, 11 would qualify as repeating in what Im trying to do. As would 79 and 78. Which is to say, any sequence of two or more numbers that appears more than once is a pattern.

Comment: well two or more is simple - because that is the  same as two which means you only have 100 possibilities to check, and then it becomes trivial. unless you need to identify the entire pattern and not just check for recurrences.

Comment: @MartinJespersen I'd like to identify the entirity of any repeated pattern of an infinite length;

Comment: Well in that case you are out of luck. Any problem involving infinity has a solution that involves infinity.

Comment: You may want to read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests.

Comment: It's unclear whether this problem is even possible to answer.  If quasi-random numbers are being generated off of a set of decimal digits in the system clock for example, this methodology will likely be completely unable to determine that the numbers are non-random.  I'm curious what this test for the probability of number is.  (Note that you will have to do a joint test on all digits simultaneously to avoid false rejection of the null.)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I missed a number of your comments above.  I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
function findLongestMatch(StringOfNumbers) {
    var matches = StringOfNumbers.match(/(.{2,})(?=.*?\1)/g);
    if (!matches) { return null; }

    var longestMatch = matches[0];
    var longestMatchLength = longestMatch.length;
    for (matchIndex = 1; matchIndex < matches.length; matchIndex++) {
      if (matches[matchIndex].length > longestMatchLength) {
        longestMatch = matches[matchIndex];
        longestMatchLength = longestMatch.length;
      }
    }
    return longestMatch;
}
```

It'll be slow, but it'll get the job done.

Comment: @GMan I've editted my response to incorporate your feedback above.  I believe I've got what you're looking for now.

Comment: That seems to be almost exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Please let me know if there's anything I can do to finish it off for you.  Also, if you like the answer, I'd greatly appreciate it if you could mark it as the accepted answer.  Good luck!